# Javascript chaining syntax in various APIs?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a term / concept / name for the various chaining styles I've seen in various javascript libraries.  I don't consider myself a "javascript person" so I stumble on the various styles of "chaining" syntax quite a bit.

Here are some examples:

```
// ember.js  
this.resource('products', function() {
  this.resource('foo', { path: '/:foo_id' });  // <-- semicolon
  this.resource('bar', { path: '/:bar_id' });  // <-- semicolon
  // additional things can go here as long as semicolons are above
});

// ember.js
songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  model: songs,               // <-- comma
  sortProperties: ['track'],  // <-- comma
  sortAscending: true         // <-- additional things if you want, use commas
});

// jasmine
beforeEach(function() {
  foo = {
    setBar: function(value) {
      bar = value;
   },                         // <-- comma
   getBar: function() {
     return bar;              // <-- additional things if you want, use commas
   }
};

// angular.js
$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {
    // ...
  }).                            // <-- period
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    // ...
  }).                            // <-- period
  // additional things can go here as long as periods are above
```

Specifically, it seems that just the trailing characters are confusing.  Do you guys grok what the API is really doing or do you just look for examples and memorize/get comfortable with it?  If it is grok'ing javascript, when you see that Ember.ArrayController.create() takes something with commas and braces then do you think:

> Braces with commas eh?  That looks like an object.  I bet .create() takes an object.

Is there a name for this chaining / stacking?  Maybe there's no name for it and it's just Javascript that I don't grok.

Comment: Different syntax (for different concepts) is different syntax. *Object literals are not "chained" properties*, albeit abusing the implementation-defined ordering of such is occasionally done. Likewise, calling side-effect methods is calling side-effect methods, regardless of any result(s) they may return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this is specific to any framework. What you are seeing is native javascript functionality.

Let's go through your examples

```
this.resource('bar', { path: '/:bar_id' });  // <-- semicolon
```

This is not chaining. The semicolon is used to signify the end of a statement in javascript.

```
songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  model: songs,               // <-- comma
  sortProperties: ['track'],  // <-- comma
  sortAscending: true         // <-- additional things if you want, use commas
});
```

Object Literals `{}` in javascript are made up of `properties`. Properties are defined using comma-separated key-value pairs:

```
var myObj = {
   myKey : "myStringValue",
   mySecondKey : "mySecondStringValue",
   myFunctionKey : function() {
      return "I am a function";
   }
}
```

More on object literals : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals

Periods are used as object accessors as such:

```
var obj = {
   myProp : myVal
};

console.log(obj.myProp); // myVal
```

Now your last example is actually function chaining:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {
    // ...
  }).                            // <-- period
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    // ...
  });
```

This occurs when a function returns a reference to it's parent object or another object containing functions:

```
var obj = {
    funcOne : function() {
        return this;
    },
    funcTwo : function() {
        return this;
    },
    funcThree : function() {
        return "NO more Chaining FOr YOU!";
    }

}

obj.funcOne().funcTwo().funcThree(); // "NO more Chaining FOr YOU!"

obj.funcOne().funcTwo().funcThree().funcFour(); // throws an error - a string cannot contain a function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent.  Perfect explanation for me.  :)  Thank you.